# How capture video from webcam to binary output stream using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam, video-streaming, c#

I need capture video from webcam to binary output stream.

I found an example how we can do this for 'region of the display' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871673/flv-stream-to-sockets-with-ffmpeg-node-js-and-socket-io) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143281/capturing-binary-output-from-process-standardoutput)

```
-loglevel panic -hide_banner -y -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f flv
```

I found another command for streaming:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Virtual-Camera" -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://10.1.0.102:1234
```

but if I understand correctly, this command sends the stream to a specific service via link and cant stream video to binary output stream